# Is it possible to automate clicking on buttons for doing testing on an Android layout?

Tags: android

I want to test the functionality of my app and would like to automate most of the user interactions. One of them being buttons(or places where one needs user interactions). Is it possible to automate such a thing or does it go against the security?

Comment: Just to give you a few keywords: Check out [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) or the [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html). I think robotium comes closer to what you want though.

Comment: How would it go against security if it's only at the developer stage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a great tutorial on simple automated UI testing for android (using JUnit):

[Automated Unit Testing the Android UI](http://www.androidacademy.com/1-tutorials/43-hands-on/152-automated-unit-testing-the-android-ui?showall=1)

and it has, among other things, this:

```
button.performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

More recent UI testing framework would be Espresso:

http://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html